# Audio playing loop в Update

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

**Задача**: при открытии игрового окна, начинается отсчёт времени, от 7 секунд до 0, при достижении 0 игровое окно закрывается, при этом отсчёт таймера должен сопровождаться звуком (тиканье часов).

**Проблема**: зацикливается звук. Сейчас реализация находится в `Update`, Как исправить ситуацию, что бы звук проигрывался раз в секунду в такт таймера и при этом не находился в условии `Update` ?

Код:

```
private bool isTimerActive = false;
private float currentTimer = 7;

void Update()
{
    if (isTimerActive) 
    {
        AudioManager.Instance.PlaySound(pointerAudioTimer, 1f); // аудио
        currentTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = currentTimer.ToString ("#");
    }
    if(currentTimer <= 0)
        Close();
}

public void Show() // Открытие окна
{
    if (currentActive)
        return;

    isTimerActive = true; // определяет начало запуска таймера
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не лучше ли будет запустить корутину в `Show`?

А так как нет особого смысла каждый кадр обновлять текст(зачем лишние перерисовки), то монжо раз в 100мс менять. Звук нужно 7 секунд крутить, значит будет 70 тиков.

```
public void Show() // Открытие окна
{
    StartCoroutine(PlaySound());
}

private IEnumerator PlaySound()
{    
    int counter = 70;
    // примерно 7 секунд будет длиться
    while (counter > 0)
    {
        timerText.text = (counter / 10).ToString ("#");
        if(counter % 10 == 0)
            AudioManager.Instance.PlaySound(pointerAudioTimer, 1f); // аудио раз в секунду

        // обновляем текст и запускаем звук каждые 100мс.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        counter--;
    }

    Close();
}
```

Единственное, я не знаю, как запуск звука у вас работает. Если `AudioManager.Instance.PlaySound` проигрывает звук один раз, то так. Если оно зацикленно проигрывает, то перед `while` запускайте, а после отключайте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он мне в текст так и выводит 70, 69, 68, можно как то сделать что бы 7, 6, 5 ?

Comment: @GR1995 `timerText.text = (counter / 10).ToString ("#");`

Comment: @GR1995 лучше не вносите правки в чужие ответы. Если есть какие-то идеи/предложения, лучше в комментариях автору про это сказать (:

Comment: ок, понял, спасибо)

Comment: @GR1995 рад был помочь)